# Combining Linq-Entity statements

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have 2 repositories, Member and Person. The Person Model contains a nullable reference property to a Member Model. The Member Model is defined in the Member Repository and I would like to put in place a pattern that ensures this stays that way. however, when I call the methods in the member repo from the person repo I get the

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable 1[...IMember] Get(..Entities,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression 1[System.Func`2[..tblMember,System.Boolean]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

While I understand this can be easily solved by putting .asEnumerable() then a second select there is a cost that means your doing 2 queries instead of one and you loose the ability to expose the method as awaitable. Below is the code I have removed a few non essential parts to clearify. I am not using lambda because I have not found a good way to say let in a lambda expression. My goal is person.Member would simply be a nested select. Also Note that the Member side of things is a very ugly database that I have not control over and these repos are being separated for a reason. Thanks in advance

```
 public class MemberRepository : Interfaces.IRepository<IMemberBase, string>
{
    private Data.LSAEntities entities { get; set; }

    public MemberRepository(Data.LSAEntities entities)
    {
        this.entities = entities;
    }


    internal static IQueryable<IMember> Get(Data.LSAEntities entities, Expression<Func<tblMember, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return (from t in entities.tblMembers.Where(predicate)
                    let options = entities.tblDataOptions.Where(o => o.DataName == "MemberStatus")
                    select new Member()
                    {
                        MemberID = t.MemberID,
                        ...
                    });
    }
}



public class PersonRepository : IRepository<IPerson, int>
{
    private Data.LSAEntities entities { get; set; }

    public PersonRepository(Data.LSAEntities entities)
    {
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    public IQueryable<IPerson> Get(int key)
    {
        return (from p in entities.tblPersons
                where p.PersonId == key
                select new Person()
                {
                    PersonId = p.PersonId,
                    ...
                    Member = MemberRepository.Get(entities, m=> p.MemberId == m.MemberID).FirstOrDefault()
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] and not just a code dump

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are intending architecturally.  If they are separate databases in reality, then you wouldn't be able to run one query to get the related data.  The error you are getting is essentially due to LINQ to Entities wanting to run the whole query at the database, where your repository method is unknown.  I think you are trying to have your cake and eat it too by enforcing boundary limitations and yet also only executing one query at the server.

Comment: Your exactly right! My goal is to enforce the repository pattern(data type mapping) on devs using the classes without having to rewrite the select statements every time I want to access the data. If my repositories had no interactions this would not be a problem however, in this case a person is releated to a member and I don't want to write select(……..) everytime I want a reference. Also by encouraging the query to compile to a single query it allows me to use async/await pattern higher up in the stack.

Comment: @johnny5 updated with minimal code

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

Given

```
var ans = from a in table
          let b = a.TotalPrice / a.Quantity
          where b > 500
          select new {
              PriceEa = b,
              a.ID,
              a.Description
          };
```

translates to

```
var ans = table.Select(a => new { b = a.TotalPrice / a.Quantity, a })
               .Where(ba => ba.b > 500)
               .Select(ba => new {
                   PriceEa = ba.b,
                   ba.a.ID,
                   ba.a.Description
                });
```

the `let` clause in query comprehension syntax in LINQ is translated to a `Select` adding a new field to hold the let value when using lambda syntax.

Comment: This is great and ill start using it instead of let however, do you have any ideas on how to make the following code work?

    Member = MemberRepository.Get(entities, m=> p.MemberId == m.MemberID).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @ChristopherSteven Look into using LINQKit.